# How do I access odoo files (such as installed add-ons folder)?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, containers, odoo-15

I've set up Odoo 15 on a container with docker compose, and am accessing the container through `remote container` extension on VS code, I've looked everywhere I can't seem to get how to access the odoo files such as the installed add-ons folder

I've set up my volumes in docker-compose file pretty much in this way:

```
 version: '3'
     services: 
      odoo:   
          image: odoo:15.0   
          env_file: .env   
          depends_on:
               - postgres   
          ports:   
               - "127.0.0.1:8069:8069"   
          volumes:     
              - data:/var/lib/odoo     
               - ./config:/etc/odoo     
              - ./extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons
```

But since I would like to apply changes on the html/css of non custom add-ons that are already present in odoo I'd have to access the source code of odoo that is present in the container (if doable).

For example in the volume `odoo-addons:/mnt/extra-addons` would be a directory where i could add my custom module but what i want is to find the source code of the add-ons already present in Odoo ?!

Answer (score 0):

Use [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose)s - it will copy the existing data from the container image into a new volume. In docker-compose you can do it, by defining a volume:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  data:
  
services:
 odoo:
  image: odoo:15.0
  env_file: .env
  depends_on: 
   - postgres
  ports:
   - "127.0.0.1:8069:8069"
  volumes:
   - data:/var/lib/odoo
   - ./config:/etc/odoo
   - ./extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons
```

If your files reside in the `/var/lib/odoo` folder you will be able to view/edit the files which are thereby accessing them in the `/var/lib/docker/volumes/{someName}_data/_data`